# Test for Equality of Parameters in Beta-Binomial Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

With binomially distributed data, it's straightforward to test the null hypothesis of equiprobable responses, $H_0: p=0.5$, but say you want to test the analogue in a Beta-Binomial model fit to over-dispersed data (not under a Bayesian paradigm, but with the whole thing fit via maximum-likelihood estimation).

It makes sense to define a null distribution where $\frac { \alpha }{ \alpha+\beta }=0.5 $, but how would you decide how large or small these values should be? Is it reasonable to simply define $\alpha+\beta$ as the observed sum $\hat\alpha+\hat\beta$ from the fitted model? Or is there reason to expect that the null would imply some different degree of dispersion?

Comment: What makes you think the data are overdispersed? Do you have a count of successes out of a total number of trials (which is >1) for every unit? Do you have an estimate of the dispersion?

Comment: Well, I mean hypothetically. Assuming that the data is over-dispersed.

Comment: If you don't have multiple trials per unit, it's hard to see how you'd know there was overdispersion present. In addition, usually, you use a measure of overdispersion from your data to fit the beta-binomial (sort of analogous to using the SD from your data to run a t-test).

Comment: Perhaps it was confusing to lead off with the different hypothetical "With Bernoulli-distributed data..." Yes, I'm assuming multiple trials per unit with over-dispersion present.